# Output multiple results with mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

What's the best way to output all results from a SELECT query?

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name,pic_url FROM accounts")) {
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    var_dump($data);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

At present dumping of `$data` only outputs one result, even though a quick check of `mysqli_num_rows()` shows two results (and there are two rows in the table).

What's the best way to output this data?

I'm essentially looking to output the `name` field and the `pic_url` for each row so I was hoping to receive my results as an array which I can then loop through using `foreach`

Comment: There is also the mysqli_fetch_all function that might be available to you.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a loop.

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple while loop and store in an array:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name,pic_url FROM accounts")) 
{    
  while ($data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
}
```